# Nodejs - Dynamic express subdomains with vhost

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, express-vhost

Id like to dynamically create subdomains for different proxies, like so:

```
var app = require('express')();
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var vhost = require('vhost');

app.get('/make', function (req, res) {
    app.use(vhost('sub1.mysite.com', proxy("www.example.com")));
});
app.listen(8080);
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?
The problem seems to be calling app.use() after the server is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get` should send back something to the client else the client will retry and then timeout.

```
var app = require('express')();
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var vhost = require('vhost');

app.get('/make', function (req, res) {
    app.use(vhost('sub1.mysite.com', proxy("www.example.com")));

    res.send('Created'); // <----- Send reply to client
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks. I could have sworn I tested this and it didn't work;

Comment: anybody can answer this problem